# When did the "Israeli accent" come into existence?

Tags: hebrew, eretz-yisrael

When did the "Israeli accent" (for speaking Hebrew) come into existence?

I believe that Hebrew as a spoken language was introduced in the late 19th century with the creation of modern Zionism. Jewish immigrants came from around the world to create the state of Israel, bringing with them a multitude of accents and native languages. Today, the Israeli pronunciation of Hebrew is notably distinct from it's Yiddish, Ladino, and other ancestors. No doubt it has evolved over time, and continues to, but when was it first codified or recognized?

Comment: Hebrew as a **vernacular** was introduced in the late 19th century.  Hebrew *was spoken* throughout the centuries, although only as part of religious rituals.

Comment: Answer, Short version: The accent originated with European Zionists who wanted to speak "authentic" (MidEastern) Hebrew, and thus consciously changed their accent to a what they considered to be more Arabic-sounding, as opposed to Yiddish and Ladino, which are based on German and Spanish, respectively. It further evolved as Hebrew speaking European settlers in Israel came into contact with actual Arabic speakers and Hebrew speakers from Arabic lands, and English speakers from the British Mandate. Nowadays, Israeli Hebrew contains many English, French, German, Arabic, and Russian loan words.

Comment: Modern Hebrew was first codified by Eliezer Ben-Yehuda in the late 19th century and early 20th century.  It continues to be codified by Academy of the Hebrew Language.  The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Hebrew) article on this subject is quite informative.